# Is a task/message queue necessary when making calls to external APIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, message-queue

I am planning a .net application in which users will be able to link their accounts to various social networking sites. Let's use twitter as an example.

A user will authorize my application to send tweets to their account.

During use, the user will be presented with a list of items. For each item, the user will be able to specify whether or not to send a tweet regarding said item.

The user should be able to look through the list of many items and mark the Tweet/Not Tweet option quickly, and then submit the form when they are done.

Each item that has been marked, will require a call to the twitter API to send the tweet. Is this a situation in which each call should be queued in some manner and executed accordingly, or would this be considered overkill(I am talking 1-5 api calls per form submission)?

Comment: Build the code so that you can always add a little Queue system when needed. That where I would start. You can always expand the functionality to use to kick back algorithm if you'll get a lot of users etc.

Comment: How responsive do you want the UI to be, if users are waiting on a response from external services it could create a very negative experience.

Comment: Users will not be waiting for a response. Basically a set and forget situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you'll build you App architecture. You might make that in clearly "async" fashion, which is most probably the case - to make it possible to "send and forget". So yes, probably you'd want some sort of ServiceBus with queuing capabilities and a lot of other things. But in the simplest case you might want just really send the request to Twitter and just don't wait until response.

Search for NServiceBus, MSMQ, CQRS principle, these things will probably help you if you want full-blown controlled async environment.